# SCORM Integration With local DB

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, drupal

I have a PHP web application, I need to integrate SCORM with my application.I know that there is cloud option for integrating SCORM. But our requirement is that saving course details into our local DB.

Please help me.

Comment: this is not very well defined question(vague). Try to edit it and ask better (I tried it like this but it doesn't work).Otherwise you ganna get bad score for wrong question

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple options for integrating SCORM content into standalone (web or otherwise) applications.

One is SCORMCloud (www.scorm.com), which gives you an integration API.  They have PHP based plugins for both WordPress and Drupal, which you can use as a guide.

SCORMCloud has a couple of methods based whereby you can bring your learner data back into your database.

When a course launch is finished, SCORMCloud will redirect back to your website.  At that point, you can hit the SCORMCloud API and fetch the results of your launch, and write that back to your database.

Our company (www.aura-software.com) produces an application integration framework for cloud based elearning sources (Vimeo, SCORMCloud, TinCan LRSs) called Bright CloudConnect.  Depending on what your integration requirements were, it can perform the same functions and a few others.  Enabling trackable elearning in existing applications is Bright's primary function.